# Can I hide or show Horizontal scrollbar in bootstrap-table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, frontend, bootstrap-table

I want to show horizontal scrollbar when bootstrap table's columns are not fitting on screen. I am using this bootstrap-table(https://bootstrap-table.com/) Any Suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=bootstrap+table+horizontal+scrollbar+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the max widht and use overflow auto, you can also try overflow scroll.
More information about overflow: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).